# renaming a 7zip extracted folder error Access i denied R

Tags: r, rename

I extracted a *TxtinOut* named folder using the following cmd in R

```
shell('7z x D:/Region02/test.7z  -oD:/Region02 -r -y')
```

I want to rename this folder *TxtinOut* to *New_Name*. I tried **file.rename()** but faced an **ERROR**: *reason 'Access is denied'*

```
file.rename("D:\\Region02\\TxtinOut", "D:\\Region02\\New_Name")
```

Can anyone suggest how I can proceed?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are in the right directory `setwd("right directory")` and that the files exist which you can check by using `list.files` or `file.exists`. You can use this code to rename your file:

```
from <- c("TxtinOut")
to <- c("New_Name")

file.rename(from, to)
```

Comment: I used the same, did not work. same error.